# Proper method to link Font awesome in PhoneGap App

Tags: font-awesome, phonegap

I am building an Android app using PhoneGap. But Font awesome icons used in the code are looking just a square shape. Before Font awesome was linked as CDN. I have removed CDN and copied it to my CSS folder. But now I am getting nothing even squares are also not visible. I checked my code in the browser source. when I click on Font awesome link in the browser it shows `Cannot GET /css/css/font-awesome.css` while the path is okay.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/font-awesome.css"><!-- icons -->
```

What will be the proper way to add Font awesome in PhoneGap App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using /css is wrong on phonegap since / is the phone root. it's better to use relative paths like:

```
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all styles -->
```

and of course don't forget to copy webfonts folder to your project www folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's saying it "Cannot GET /css/css/font-awesome.css", but you can't just download the Font Awesome CSS file because the CSS file references font files, so you need to download everything.

Go to https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself and download everything. Then unzip it and put your app's www folder and include `<link href="your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">` in your HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about this but my guess is you need to link to `font-awesome.min` file and in my case `css/CSSIcons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

Can you check this for me buddy and let me know if it works